# Android Studio Gradle Timeout Error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to open an existing android project in android studio, however when I try to refresh and build gradle I get an error; "Gradle 'project name' project refresh failed: Error: Connection timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle." However, I am not behind a proxy. Additionally, it takes a very long time for the whole build process, approximately 1 hour 30 minutes. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Try building the app after setting gradle to offline.

File->Settings->Gradle and set 'offline' to checked. This will build the app within seconds.

When you want to download any libraries just set 'offline' to unchecked and build.

Answer (score 0):

choose working proxy
and set it in gradle.properties
like this:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9666
```